# MVC3 JQuery parseHtml showing the text of the html

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to use the blue imp file uploader and need ie 8 support. After uploading I am returning HTML and javascript to change the content of the popup window the user sent the upload from to indicate success or failure. No matter what I try, when the html and javascript is returned it is being displayed in the form as text.

Here is what I am doing. (Some info has been sanitized to hide the company I work for)

1. I am taking a partial view and rendering it as string, Html encoding it, and returning it as text/plain as recommended.
     string partialView = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(RenderPartialViewToString("~/Areas/MyView", null));
           return Json(partialView, "text/plain");

The raw response in fiddler is
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: ASP.NET Development Server/10.0.0.0
Date: Wed, 21 May 2014 20:59:46 GMT
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-AspNetMvc-Version: 3.0
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 3151
Connection: Close

"\u0026lt;script type=\u0026quot;text/javascript\u0026quot;\u0026gt;\r\n    $(document).ready(function () {\r\n        InitializeLayout(\u0026#39;#divContent\u0026#39;);\r\n    });\r\n\u0026lt;/script\u0026gt;\r\n\r\n\u0026lt;div id=\u0026quot;divContentConfirmation\u0026quot;\u0026gt;\r\n    \u0026lt;table\u0026gt;\r\n        \u0026lt;colgroup\u0026gt;\r\n            \u0026lt;col width=\u0026quot;2%\u0026quot; /\u0026gt;\r\n            \u0026lt;col width=\u0026quot;98%\u0026quot; /\u0026gt;\r\n            \u0026lt;col width=\u0026quot;2%\u0026quot; /\u0026gt;\r\n        \u0026lt;/colgroup\u0026gt;\r\n        \u0026lt;tr\u0026gt;\r\n            \u0026lt;td\u0026gt;\u0026amp;nbsp;\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n            \u0026lt;td\u0026gt;\u0026lt;img alt=\u0026quot;\u0026quot; src= \u0026quot;/Content/Images/RisingVision.gif\u0026quot; /\u0026gt;\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n            \u0026lt;td\u0026gt;\u0026amp;nbsp;\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n        \u0026lt;/tr\u0026gt;\r\n        \u0026lt;tr\u0026gt;\r\n            \u0026lt;td\u0026gt;\u0026amp;nbsp;\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n            \u0026lt;td class=\u0026quot;BlueCellBG\u0026quot;\u0026gt;\u0026amp;nbsp;\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n            \u0026lt;td\u0026gt;\u0026amp;nbsp;\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n        \u0026lt;/tr\u0026gt;\r\n        \u0026lt;tr class=\u0026quot;SectionHeaderText\u0026quot;\u0026gt;\r\n              \u0026lt;td\u0026gt;\u0026amp;nbsp;\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n              \u0026lt;td\u0026gt;Thank you. Your message has been submitted.\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n              \u0026lt;td\u0026gt;\u0026amp;nbsp;\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n        \u0026lt;/tr\u0026gt;\r\n        \u0026lt;tr\u0026gt;\u0026lt;td\u0026gt;\u0026amp;nbsp;\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\u0026lt;td\u0026gt;\u0026amp;nbsp;\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\u0026lt;/tr\u0026gt;\r\n        \u0026lt;tr class=\u0026quot;SectionHeaderText\u0026quot;\u0026gt;\r\n              \u0026lt;td\u0026gt;\u0026amp;nbsp;\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n              \u0026lt;td\u0026gt;What Happens Next:\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n              \u0026lt;td\u0026gt;\u0026amp;nbsp;\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n        \u0026lt;/tr\u0026gt;\r\n        \u0026lt;tr\u0026gt;\r\n              \u0026lt;td\u0026gt;\u0026amp;nbsp;\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n              \u0026lt;td\u0026gt;You will receive an email in 24 hours confirming that we have your request for assitance. it \u0026lt;br /\u0026gt;will include a tracking number which you can use when communicating with Rising.\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n              \u0026lt;td\u0026gt;\u0026amp;nbsp;\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n        \u0026lt;/tr\u0026gt;\r\n        \u0026lt;tr \u0026gt;\r\n            \u0026lt;td colspan=\u0026quot;3\u0026quot; align=\u0026quot;right\u0026quot;\u0026gt;\u0026lt;input type=\u0026quot;button\u0026quot; name=\u0026quot;btnClose\u0026quot; value=\u0026quot;Close\u0026quot; id=\u0026quot;btnClose\u0026quot; onclick=\u0026quot;ClosePopup();\u0026quot;/\u0026gt;\u0026lt;/td\u0026gt;\r\n        \u0026lt;/tr\u0026gt;\r\n    \u0026lt;/table\u0026gt;\r\n\u0026lt;/div\u0026gt;\r\n"

My "Done" method looks like this:

```
done: function (e, data) {
                var text;
                if (data.responseText)
                    text = data.responseText;
                else {
                    text = data.result;
                }
                self.triggerButton.prop("disabled", false);
                var json = $.parseJSON(text);

                var html = $.parseHTML(json);
                self.targetDiv.html(html[0], document, true);
            }
```

I will go through each variable
var text is the output above, but with double quotes surrounding it

var json is

```
 "&lt;script type=&quot;text/javascript&quot;&gt;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        InitializeLayout(&#39;#divPopupConfirmation&#39;);
    });
&lt;/script&gt;

&lt;div id=&quot;divPopupConfirmation&quot;&gt;
    &lt;table&gt;
        &lt;colgroup&gt;
            &lt;col width=&quot;2%&quot; /&gt;
            &lt;col width=&quot;98%&quot; /&gt;
            &lt;col width=&quot;2%&quot; /&gt;
        &lt;/colgroup&gt;
        &lt;tr&gt;
            &lt;td&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;td&gt;&lt;img alt=&quot;&quot; src= &quot;/Content/Images/RisingVision.gif&quot; /&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;td&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;tr&gt;
            &lt;td&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;td class=&quot;BlueCellBG&quot;&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;
            &lt;td&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;tr class=&quot;SectionHeaderText&quot;&gt;
              &lt;td&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;
              &lt;td&gt;Thank you. Your message has been submitted.&lt;/td&gt;
              &lt;td&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;tr class=&quot;SectionHeaderText&quot;&gt;
              &lt;td&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;
              &lt;td&gt;What Happens Next:&lt;/td&gt;
              &lt;td&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;tr&gt;
              &lt;td&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;
              &lt;td&gt;You will receive an email in 24 hours confirming that we have your request for assitance. it &lt;br /&gt;will include a tracking number which you can use when communicating with Rising.&lt;/td&gt;
              &lt;td&gt;&amp;nbsp;&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;
        &lt;tr &gt;
            &lt;td colspan=&quot;3&quot; align=&quot;right&quot;&gt;&lt;input type=&quot;button&quot; name=&quot;btnClose&quot; value=&quot;Close&quot; id=&quot;btnClose&quot; onclick=&quot;ClosePopUp();&quot;/&gt;&lt;/td&gt;
        &lt;/tr&gt;
    &lt;/table&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;
"
```

var html is

```
  "<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        InitializeLayout('#divPopupConfirmation');
    });
</script>

<div id="divPopupConfirmation">
    <table>
        <colgroup>
            <col width="2%" />
            <col width="98%" />
            <col width="2%" />
        </colgroup>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><img alt="" src= "/Content/Images/RisingVision.gif" /></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="BlueCellBG">&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="SectionHeaderText">
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>Thank you. Your message has been submitted.</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
        <tr class="SectionHeaderText">
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>What Happens Next:</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>You will receive an email in 24 hours confirming that we have your request for assitance. it <br />will include a tracking number which you can use when communicating with Rising.</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td colspan="3" align="right"><input type="button" name="btnClose" value="Close" id="btnClose" onclick="ClosePopUp();"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
"
```

This string is what is displaying in the pop up. The HTML and scripts are not being parsed. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I should have known it when I saw the extra double quote on each end. I thought `.parseHTML` was also decoding, but it was leaving the single quotes around the whole block, meaning I was outputting a string and not `html/javascript`. All it took was a quick inspection with Developers tools after the callback finished.

I changed the JavaScript to

```
var json = $.parseJSON(text);
var decodedHtml = $("<div/>").html(json).text();                     
self.targetDiv.html(decodedHtml, document, true);
```